# Upgrading OpenSSL to version 3.0.2 from source

Tags: openssl

In light of the current security issues with openssl 1.1.1x we had to upgade our (Ubuntu) systems from source, as apt only showed that the latest openssl (1.1.1f) was the newest

**UPDATE**
[CVE-2022-0778](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20220315.txt)

after running sudo apt update/upgrade, openssl was still version 1.1.1f, which is vulnerable - at least on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I’m not sure how better to explain it, beyond what I wrote in my answer; but Ubuntu’s `openssl` will still say it is 1.1.1f, even though it has the security fixes for CVE-2022-0778. If `dpkg -l libssl1.1` reports version 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12, you’re fine.

Comment: some of our systems are arm64 and report ii  libssl1.1:arm64            1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~1 arm64  after updating - this one is running 18.04 - do you think this is safe?

Comment: See the [security notice](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5328-1) I linked to in my answer, it lists all the fixed versions in still-supported Ubuntu releases — `libssl1.1`  1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.15 for 18.04. Your output is truncated, but you should be safe.

Answer (score 7):

as root: (or use sudo)

```
$ sudo su
# cd /usr/src
# wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.2.tar.gz
# tar zxvf openssl-3.0.2.tar.gz
# cd openssl-3.0.2
# ./Configure
# make
# make install
```

if you have an old version of OpenSSL installed, you may have to do:

```
# cd /usr/lib/ssl
# unlink openssl.cnf
# ln -s /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf openssl.cnf
# ldconfig
# openssl version
```

if you see OpenSSL 3.0.2 - it was successful

otherwise, if you receive an error that openssl could not be found or something

if you have an x86_64 architecture

```
# ldconfig /usr/local/lib64
```

Comment: Beware the version change may not be reflected in the "openssl version" command at a bash shell prompt due to shell cache. To clear the shell's cache, use the hash -r command.

Comment: or `sudo reboot` then followed by the last line above `ldconfig /usr/local/lib64`

Answer (score 3):

Even though [the versions of OpenSSL in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl) correspond to older versions, they are patched to include fixes for known security issues.

For example, in 20.04 (the latest LTS):

```
openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12) focal-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: Infinite loop in BN_mod_sqrt()
    - debian/patches/CVE-2022-0778-1.patch: fix infinite loop in
      crypto/bn/bn_sqrt.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2022-0778-2.patch: add documentation of
      BN_mod_sqrt() in doc/man3/BN_add.pod.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2022-0778-3.patch: add a negative testcase for
      BN_mod_sqrt in test/bntest.c, test/recipes/10-test_bn_data/bnmod.txt.
    - CVE-2022-0778
```

In 21.10 (the latest release):

```
openssl (1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2) impish-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: Infinite loop in BN_mod_sqrt()
    - debian/patches/CVE-2022-0778-1.patch: fix infinite loop in
      crypto/bn/bn_sqrt.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2022-0778-2.patch: add documentation of
      BN_mod_sqrt() in doc/man3/BN_add.pod.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2022-0778-3.patch: add a negative testcase for
      BN_mod_sqrt in test/bntest.c, test/recipes/10-test_bn_data/bnmod.txt.
    - CVE-2022-0778
```

See also [the corresponding security notice](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5328-1).

On supported releases of Ubuntu (and other distributions), you shouldn’t ever need to build software yourself to address security issues, as long as you keep your installations updated.